# Getting values from xml file

Tags: xml, android-studio

I have this code and I want my code to be clean and easy to modify

```
<TextView
    ...
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/appNameColor"
    ...
```

I want to make the textSize same with textColor, I want all my values the same and makes my editing easier. like the code below

```
<TextView
    ...
    android:textSize="@fontSize/titleFontSize"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/appNameColor"
    ...
```

My myFontSize.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <fontSize name="titleFontSize">50sp</size>
</resources>
```

and this error

```
Unknown resource type fontSize less... (Ctrl+FI) 
Inspection info: Validates resource references inside Android XML files.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please review: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources

`fontSize` is not a valid resource type. You want to set a value for a font size, which is measured in `sp` which is a *dimension* resource, so you would use the `dimen` resource type:

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="titleFontSize">50sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: It works! I thought resource type is a variable name and any name will do,I learn something today, thank you.